# How to use vagrant with browser sync for gulp?

Tags: vagrant, gulp

i want to know if someone is using browser sync with vagrant, it is posible?
how do you configure it? I tried to read if there is something on the web, but nothing clear to me. Are there other service to use livereload to all devices at the same time ?

Comment: http://quick.as/q0rs9jz, but does not give much info.

Comment: gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "mypage.lcl:8000/"
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

If your vagrant box is running, you should be able to access your website through the domain you chose. For this example, let's assume your site is loaded via `mysite.local`

In your `gulpfile.js` you'll need to set up a proxy, like so:

```
// gulpfile.js

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {  
  browserSync.init(["path/to/your/css/*.css", "path/to/your/js/*.js"],

    // The magic line. Point the proxy to your local domain
    { proxy: "mysite.local" }
  );
});
```

Restart gulp if it's already running and you should see an IP address in your command line:

[image]

Take note of the port number (in this case, `:3000`)

Now go to `http://mysite.local:3000` -- Notice the port! You must add the port that is shown in your command line. BrowserSync will connect!

**Note:** If it does not work, a cache could be your problem. Try adding a random query string to the end of your URL to get around a caching issue. Example: `http://mysite.local:3000/?t=1`